# To display employee's leave which is same department

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to display the employee's leaves which is same department with me. I only want the employee which same department with me but the output show all of the employee in database

Here is my database

table leave:{Leave_ID(PK), Data_Apply, Leave_Type, Status, Emp_ID(FK)}

table employee:  {Emp_ID(PK), Emp_Name, Dept_ID(FK)}

table department:  {Dept_ID(PK), Dept_Name, Dept_Desc}

As a example I'm head of department of Marketing and I want to see employee's leave detail who under me and in a same department. I tried to use function in_array to display but fail.

Here is my code

```
<?php
        //$test = mysql_query("select * from employee");
        //if(in_array($search["Dept_ID"], array($test)))

        $result = mysql_query("select * from `leave`");
            if ($result == FALSE)
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["Leave_ID"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Emp_ID"];?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $row["Date_Apply"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Leave_Type"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Status"];?></td>
        <td><a href="app_status.php?id=<?php echo $row['Leave_ID'];?>" target = "_blank">Profile</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

Is there is any function or anything as a suggestion to used. I'm a newbie in programming and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Maybe you need to attach a condition

Comment: do you want this done in PHP or SQL?  it might be easier to do in the query instead of trying to filter through a PHP array.  also, based on the table structure you provided, it's not possible to tell any department hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$department_id = 4; 

$result = mysql_query(' select l.* 
                       from   leave as l 
                              join employee as e
                                 on l.emp_id = e.emp_id 
                       where  e.dept_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($department_id)); 


$department_name = 'this one'; 

$result = mysql_query(" select l.*
                       from   leave as l 
                              join employee as e
                                 on l.emp_id = e.emp_id 
                              join department as e
                                 on d.dept_id = e.dept_id 
                       where  d.dept_name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($department_name))."%'");
```

---

**edit**

After reading the first comment down there, I think you're saying that you essentially have an `employee_id` and you want to filter the query by that employee's department.  So... here's some code to do that:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41bf7/1/0

There are two queries there... they're about the same so I would just choose which ever is easier for you to understand.  You would add them to the PHP like this (using the first query from the sql fiddle):

```
$logged_in_employee_id = 1; 

$result = mysql_query('select e.emp_id, e.emp_name, 
                              l.date_apply, l.leave_type, l.status, 
                              d.dept_name, d.dept_desc

                       from   `leave` as l 

                              join employee as e
                                 on l.emp_id = e.emp_id 

                              join department as d
                                 on d.dept_id = e.dept_id 

                       where  d.dept_id in ( 
                                select  dd.dept_id  
                                from    employee as ee 
                                        join department as dd
                                           on dd.dept_id = ee.dept_id    
                                where   ee.emp_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($logged_in_employee_id)).' )');
```

I'm not sure where you're getting the `employee_id` or the `department_id` but make sure you **sanitize and validate** anything you put into a query like this.  I am using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) which helps but that query will still break if someone hijacks your `POST` data (or something) and uses a string instead of an integer value.  There are some great posts on StackOverflow about how to do this; just search for sanitizing input, sql injection with PHP, and how to do prepared statements or use PDO.

Comment: So, is it possible to write a mysql_query statement or anything to see the staff in my department only without initiate the value like "$department = 4" because if I log in as another user with different department it will still going to display the same department as I had give a value to $department_id as shown at above.

Comment: I edited my answer up there.  Let me know if that's what you need.  If not, tell me _what value you do have_ that you want to use as a filter for the query.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm searching. I have solve the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query (at the moment it takes all the records in "leave" table).
Assuming that you know the code of your department, you can use something similar (not tested):

```
SELECT leave.*, employee.Emp_Name, department.Dept_Name, department.Dept_Desc
FROM leave, employee, department
WHERE leave.Emp_ID=employee.Emp_ID
  AND department.Dept_ID=employee.Dept_ID
  AND department.Dept_ID="<your department ID>"
```

Comment: i don't think department is actually joined with any other table in your query... it would result in a cross join.